'self' or 'this' reference oop functionality in PLAIN C
I'm using pseudo oop paradigm with plain c, and would like to be able to have a struct function pointer have access to the rest of the structure data.
The only way I've been able to do this is by passing the 'current object' reference in each function eg
struct MyStructure{
    //NOTE I want to access this member:
    struct MyStructure *self;
    
    int var1;
    int var2;
    
    void ( *initMemberFn    )(MyStructure *self, int arg1, int arg2);
    void ( *memberFn1       )(MyStructure *self);
    
};

void initMemberFn(MyStructure *self, int arg1, int arg2){   
    (*self).var1 = arg1;
    (*self).var2 = arg2;
    
}

void memberFn1(MyStructure *self){
    //NOTE Access the above member HERE without passing the self argument
    printf("var1:%d, var2:%d", (*self).var1, (*self).var2 );
    
}


int main(){
    
    MyStructure mystruct;
    mystruct.self = &mystruct;

    mystruct.initMemberFn = &initMemberFn;
    mystruct.memberFn1 = &memberFn1;

    mystruct.initMemberFn(mystruct.self, 1, 2);
    mystruct.memberFn1(mystruct.self);
    
}

I'll note this doesn't seem to work on all compilers but I am using visual studio's cl.exe.
Is there any (other) way I can access the structure's self member from inside one of the functions?
(I've noted the relevant lines with comments.)

You could use a macro for that, such as CALL_MEMBER(struct_name, method_name). Otherwise, there is no way because your functions can be called for different "instances" of MyStructure and they have no way of knowing which one.

Add (*self).self = self; to initMemberFn()?

The usual way is to pass in &mystruct directly -- I think you get negative value from having a self field in your struct which is required to be the same as address of the struct. You might define a macro to avoid specifying the object twice.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I tried that, it works for assigning it but doesn't allow access from inside.

Side note, C has an operator specifically so you don't have to write (*self).var. Use self->var instead

@Verpous I'll have to start using that -- I always get my pointer operators confused in c

The address stored by mystruct.self = &mystruct; will be wrong when you assign the whole structure like mystruct1 = mystruct2; or pass the structure by value to a function.

The code is missing a typedef for the type MyStructure.

I don't see any point to putting a self pointer into the structure.  Any code positioned to access that pointer must also be positioned to easily compute it.  That is, anywhere I could use my_struct.self to get a pointer to the struct, I could more reliably use &my_struct.  And anywhere I could use p->self, I could more reliably use just p.

One (slightly blasphemous) way is to change the file extension to .cpp and see the compiler do the work for you. :-) As a C++ user myself, I find it slightly amusing that the C code wastes the space of 3 pointers in a two int struct, and needs extra code to initalize the pointers. C++ does not...

Also, a standard comment is that Bjarne used macros to add classes to C already in the 1970s. It failed miserably, so eventually he had to design himself a new language.

@JohnBollinger I was mostly just trying to see if I could mimic python syntax although I can imagine a situation in which the original &my_struct could go out of scope.

@stackoverflow909, no matter what, to do something along these lines in C, each function needs to accept a pointer to the object to operate upon.  Such an API design is not so unusual.  You can call that parameter self if you like.  In the function you then have self->var1 or (less idiomatic) (*self).var1.  Additional indirection doesn't improve on that syntactically or semantically, but it does increase the cross section for error.


Is there any (other) way I can access the structure's self member from inside one of the functions?

No.
C has no notion of object methods like C++ (or other OOP languages), only global functions.
From the point of view of the function there is no self/this etc. unless you pass it as a parameter explicitly.
The fact that the function is called via a function pointer stored in the struct makes no relevant difference.
As suggested in a comment you can use a marco for making the call a bit shorter, but it will not change this basic fact, only hide it to some extent (which I personaly find less clear).
A side note:
In OOP languages like C++,C#, etc. it will actually under the hood be the same as in C, i.e. a pointer or reference to the current object will be passed to the function in the code generated by the compiler.

OOP compilers do (almost) exactly what you wrote automatically, i.e. implicitly pass this pointer as first argument. Some compilers (specifically MSVC) pass this via register, even if all other arguments are passed via stack. Exact implementation is up to compiler though and is not mandated by C++ spec.
Non-OOP compilers of course don't do this and you need pass all arguments explicitly, including this (or self in your example).
"Almost exactly" is because no point in adding self member into MyStructure as it doesn't serve any benefit, only takes space in memory.

"Almost exactly" is also because OOP languages do not need to store the method function pointers in the objects.

@IanAbbott Neither should you do so in C, because that just takes up a lot of extra space needlessly. For inheritance purposes one may create an external vtable outside the struct.

@IanAbbott well it is not mandated by spec as well. Compiler implementation can do it either way. But yes I agree, normal compiler would include pointer to general "class struct" with all function pointers rather than duplicate all pointers in every object.

For C++ objects, there is a nice description of size contributions in this answer although the author seems confused about the concept of padding.

he takes very trivial case when class defined and immediately used within same module. Obviously compiler can optimize and bypass storing class information in memory. Each member function invocation is like calling regular function with extra parameter. However once object pointer is passed to external functions and virtual member exist - here can start complications. In any case, as I said I agree with you. Yet exact memory layout is not very important in the context of this question.

In the OO languages that I know about, that's done by implicitly passing a reference to the instance to instance methods. For example, C++ and Swift both pass a reference to the instance as the first parameter in instance methods. If you ever look at the assembly code generated for an instance method, you'll see it.
You can't do that in C, so you'll have to pass the reference explicitly, as you've done for void memberFn1(MyStructure *self).

What do you mean by implicitly? Like the oo language has a built in macro?

@stackoverflow909 It means that the notation object.method(a,b,c) is a syntactic sugar for calling method(&object, a,b,c) (well, kind of).

@EugeneSh. Yeah, I had a feeling that's what it was, cause I think it's... python? that requires you pass (or define?) self as a parameter for member functions.

yeah, you can see the hints in Python, Rust and such

Right, what @EugeneSh. said. A big difference between member functions and other functions is that the former get a this pointer as the first parameter, even though you don't see it in the code (which is what makes it "implicit"). The compiler handles it; you don't see it as a user, but you know that you can refer to this in any member function.

When writing proper OO design in C, the first thing you have to come to terms with is that you can't have "C++-like syntax". Do not have member functions as function pointers part of the struct. They take up extra space and prevent inlining, but also as you noticed, there is no this and so you'll have to pass along the current object with the function call.
We then come to the conclusion that instead of writing code like obj.member(&obj, params) we might as well just write member(&obj, params). Member functions are declared as any function at file scope, but inside your "class" and not necessarily public. There is absolutely nothing in OO design saying that member functions must be called through obj.member(), because OO is a way to design programs and does not specify implementation details. Check out How to do private encapsulation in C?
It is however possible to declare instances of member functions in a separate virtual table for inheritance/polymorphism. This table then sits as a static private container with function pointers, declared at file scope, so there's just one instance of it instead of one per class. (Mind thread safety if required.)
